# No repository for "AlicuotasIva" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have an application with nestjs and typeorm.
When running in development mode everything works fine.

The error occurs when debugging in vscode.

[This is my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr3wX.png)

launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Backend",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/backend/src/main.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy",
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register",
                "-r",
                "tsconfig-paths/register"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/backend",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        }
    ]
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "*",
    "database": "database",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "supportBigNumbers": true,
    "bigNumberStrings": false,
    "synchronize": false
  }
```

I appreciate if you can help me

Comment: Do you have webpack enabled on your nest-cli.json ?

Comment: This is my nest-cli.json: `{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "webpack": true
  }
}`

Comment: Webpack does not compile the ormconfig.json  you should import the configuration on the TypeOrmforRootAsync/TypeOrmforRoot, but first, try deleting this line: "compilerOptions": {     "webpack": true   }

Comment: Delete the line "compilerOptions": {"webpack": true}, but keep getting the same error.

Comment: I just fixed the problem as follows: in `ormconfig.json` change `"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],` with `"entities": ["{src, dist}/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],`. 
I hope someone helps

Comment: That's a weird solution, do you know what's the command used by vscode to launch the app ?

Comment: With the aforementioned change, dubug now works, but not development mode. `npm run start:dev`. Now it's throwing error

Comment: This is my main.ts: `import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  
  app.enableCors();

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true
    })
  );

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();`

Comment: Go to the file where you define your TypeOrmModule.forRoot() and change it for this:

Comment: `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get('PGHOST'),
        port: +configService.get<number>('PGPORT'),
        username: configService.get('PGUSER'),
        password: configService.get('PGPASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('PGDATABASE'),
        entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
        logging: true,
      }),
    }),`

Comment: Remember that you must initialize the ConfigModule and set the env variables

Comment: after that please delete the file ormconfig.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now if it works, both in debugging and development mode. I clarify that I install dotenv and in my app.module add `require ('dotenv'). Config ();` Thank you very much